# Export audio to GarageBand with UiActivityController

Tags: ios

I'm trying to export an audio file from my app to GarageBand, but when I launch UiActivityController other apps appear but no GarageBand. I've tried mp3 and m4r audio formats. Is there any way to share an audio file with GarageBand?

Comment: First of all, make sure it's not hidden, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68923260/3585796). Generally, it depends on whether their app supports this feature, have you seen such possibility(to export to GarageBand) in any other app?

Comment: Yes, RingtoneMaker does it. It seems that it creates a .band folder containing a GarageBand project, so when sharing it, of course, GarageBand can open it. I wonder how to create a GarageBand project in my app...